# git rebase/merge/cherry-pick a commit that rearranges a block of code

Tags: git

Suppose a *master* branch and a *feature* branch have the same piece of code originally:

```
Block A
Block B
```

where Block A and Block B can be arbitrary lines of code. Now, in the *master* branch, Block A is changed, e.g.

```
**Block A**
Block B
```

And then, in the *feature* branch, Block A is moved after Block B, i.e.

```
Block B
Block A
```

What git think I'm doing is deleting Block A and adding some new lines after Block B, so if I try to

1. Merge *feature* branch into *master*,
2. Rebase *feature* branch on *master*, or
3. Cherry-pick *feature* in the *master* branch,

a conflict happens:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
**Block A**
=======
>>>>>>> Move Block A behind Block B
Block B
Block A
```

A conflict is expected, but the problem here is, git cannot help update the changes in Block A.
Is there a better solution to this situation? For example, somehow make git think that I am deleting Block B and adding stuff before Block A?

(I would welcome any suggestions for a better title.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no better way, at the moment, to deal with this than to resolve the conflict at merge time: simply pick the new Block A code and the updated Block B code from the two "sides" of the merge.  (This may be easier if you set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3` so that you can see, in the conflicted file, how the code was laid out in the merge base version.  If you use various merge tools, this may not make any difference, so whether to set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3` is up to you.)

A future, smarter diff and merge algorithm might be able to figure this out and give you a simpler merge conflict to resolve, or even resolve it on its own.  But that's not available in Git today.

Comment: Or a less smart (but still smarter than today's) merge algorithm finds that B was moved before A rather than A after B. That would not lead to a conflict, perhaps. ;)